# Select orders based on number of adults and children

Tags: orders

I am trying to develop a website for travel agency, I wanted to know is there a option to provide the user with number of adults and number of children. Where the price for children is lesser than for adults.

Answer (score 0):

First create 2 attributes for number of adults and number of children
Then, you can create a configurable product and then create simple products based on those 2 attributes you created.

In the simple product for adults , set the desired price for adults and
for simple products for children set the price for children

Then link those simple products to the configurable products ..

If you need help in creating configurable products then you can refer this 
http://www.sitepoint.com/adding-configurable-products-magento-ecommerce-site/